# How to get EST date time without changing Machine Time Zone and writing timezone conversion code?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone, currentculture

My machine time zone is IST therefore when I check `DateTime.Now` in C# it will always show current datetime of that timezone. I have to get datetime in EST when I do `DateTime.Now`. I don't want to change timezone of machine and don't want to convert current datetime to EST writing time conversion code using timezone id.

The reason is I read somewhere in article that when you change currentculture the system would behave that way so `DateTime.Now` also should give me date in EST. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get DateTime.Now for a specific TimeZone regardless of the device timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434766/get-datetime-now-for-a-specific-timezone-regardless-of-the-device-timezone)

Comment: I have to get datetime in EST when I do DateTime.Now - Why??? Why don't you get current UTC time and convert it to any timezone you wish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The reason is I read somewhere in article that when you change currentculture the system would behave that way so DateTime.Now also should give me date in EST. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Ok, I will correct you.  You are wrong (sorry).

`DateTime.Now` always returns the local time based on the operating system's local time zone setting.  It is not affected by changes to `CurrentCulture`.  Changing the current culture can affect the display format and the calendar system used when creating a string from a `DateTime`, but it does not affect the `DateTime` itself, and thus does not affect the time zone either.

In general, culture or locale settings are orthogonal to time zones.  For example, if I am an English speaking American temporarily visiting Japan, my culture would likely be `en-US`, and my time zone would likely be `Tokyo Standard Time`.

Comment: Thanks @Matt for clarification. I understood.