# TimeZoneInfo ConvertTimeFromUtc discrepancies during utc date change

Tags: c#, datetime, xunit

I was trying to convert Utc date to specific timezone current date using following code

```
var nowUtcDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
var localDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(nowUtcDate.Date, TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("America/Los_Angeles")).Date;

if(someDueDate == localDate){
  ...
}
```

To my surprise localDate was resulting in 6/9/2023 while Utc date was 6/10/2023. Where I was expecting it to be 6/10/2023. After sometime I changed the logic to create timezoneinfo object. And now it was giving correct localDate which was 6/10/2023.

```
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/Los_Angeles")
```

Instead of

```
TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("America/Los_Angeles")
```

I thought it was something to do with TimeZoneConverter library. But somehow I had feeling that it has to do with Utc date change. I have put back the old code and ran it again this time it was giving me the correct date (6/10/2023). The only change was Utc Date was changed from 6/10/2023 to 6/11/2023 during the test process.

I'm attaching the screenshot of Immediate Window where I ran the command during testing. I have highlighted it with red and green section to see the difference.

- Testing Date: 6/10/2023
- Time Duration : 6:50 PM - 7:15 PM CST
- OS/Server: Windows 10 PRO Local machine
- UTC Date range: 6/10/2023(11:50 PM) - 6/11/2023(12:07 AM)
  [image]

**Update:** Original requirement is to get the current datetime in a time zone. And compare it to a date stored in db. As an example from below pic, when I pass Auckland time zone, I should get the 06/12/2023 02:00 AM. Similarly with other time zones. I initially used answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434766/get-datetime-now-for-a-specific-timezone-regardless-of-the-device-timezone) SO question to get expected output. However I have altered it to use **date** property that made the outcomes confusing.

As pointed out in the answer using **DateTime.UtcNow** as part of the statement have resolved the issue.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you find surprising.  When you do `nowUtcDate.Date`, that returns to you a DateTime object representing midnight on that date.  Midnight on 2023-06-10 in UTC would be 4 PM on 2023-06-09 in PDT.  I can't tell what you were expecting.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't access the `Date` property on `nowUtcDate`? That always makes it midnight UTC. And since Los Angeles has a negative UTC offset, it will always be the previous day when you convert that to Los Angeles.

Comment: That said, even if you don't access `Date`, you should still expect that it will be the previous day in Los Angeles for *some* `DateTime`. These timezones have different offsets after all. Please show some of your expected inputs and outputs.

Comment: I was expecting the output in PDT would be 6/10/2023 whereas actual output was 6/9/2023. But I see your point, I should have not used Date property, Today property would have given me expected output. I will try that.

Comment: Is this something to do with Day Light Savings time. The time sample your using is during DST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `Date` property on `nowUtcDate`. `Date` returns a `DateTime` that is the same date as `nowUtcDate`, but with the time set to 00:00:00. For the time you showed - 2023-06-10T23:50:00Z, this returns 2023-06-10T00:00:00Z.

You then convert 2023-06-10T00:00:00Z to Los Angeles' timezone. Since Los Angeles is at a UTC offset of -7 hours, this subtracts 7 hours from 2023-06-10T00:00:00, giving the result 2023-06-09T17:00:00. The date part is one day before the UTC day.

Note that this operation will always produce a date that is one day before the date of `nowUtcDate`, no matter what `nowUtcDate` is. This is because you are always subtracting from the midnight of `nowUtcDate`.

You probably have meant:

```
var localDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(nowUtcDate, TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("America/Los_Angeles")).Date;
```

When `nowUtcDate` is 2023-06-10T23:50:00Z, this gives you the same date - 2023-06-10. Because subtracting 7 hours from 23:50 does not change the date.

When `nowUtc` is 2023-06-11T00:07:00Z (the other `DateTime` you have given) however, the date in Los Angeles is different, because subtracting 7 hours from 00:07 changes the date to the previous day. If this is surprising to you, your expectation is wrong, or you are not actually trying to convert 2023-06-11T00:07:00Z to Los Angeles' timezone.